# doing a loop with data imported from outside file

Tags: c++

I have a data.txt file which holds 5 numbers: 32 99 135 0 -999 my program was supposed to get all first numbers from the file one by one in that order, calculate the Fahrenheit of those numbers and store it into a file called result.txt. All all those process should be automatic after u click debug. But I do not know how my program will jump from 1 number to another.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define in file "data.txt"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int carry;
    int fah;
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
       fin.open ("data.txt");
       fout.open ("result.txt");
    fin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    fout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e;
        for( a; a > -999; a--)
        {
        fah = a *9/5+32;
        cout << "The Fahrenheit of "<< a << " is " << fah << ".";
        }
}
```

Comment: The expressions `a,b,c,d != -999` and `a, a!= -999, a--` does *not* work as you think they should. Read about [the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: Also, what do you think `exit;` will accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

`while ( a, a!= -999, a--)` does not do what you expected to do. A `while` can onyl have a single termination condition. You need a `for`looop like this:

`for( a=0; a > -999; a--)`

This is a loop with a control variable `a`. At the bgeinning `a` is set to `0`. Each run `a` is decremented by `1`. The loop terminates when `a` becomes `-999`.

IF you like to use a `while` loop for instead you have to do it like this:

```
while ( a > -999 )
{
    ... your code ...
    a--;
}
```

This `if ( a,b,c,d != -999)` does not work anyway. If you like to test if `a` is not `-999` and `b` not `-999` and `c` not is `-999` and `d` is not `-999`, you have to write it like this:

`if ( a != -999 && b != -999 && c != -999 && d != -999)`